# Sqoop error while loading data from MySQL to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am running a sqoop to load data from MySQL to HDFS.
Here is the code:

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://test.xxx.net/LIVE \
--username pitt \
--password abcd \
--query "select * from tblMfg where 1=1 and \$CONDITIONS" \
--target-dir /user/pitt/tblMfg \
--fields-terminated-by '\t' \
--null-string '' \
--null-non-string '' \
-m 1
```

On tblMfg:

```
Value of dateCreate column: 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Data type of dateCreate column: timestamp
```

But when I run the sqoop, I get this error:

```
java.io.IOException: SQLException in nextKeyValue

0000-00-00 00:00:00�� 08:06:05��05����015-04-20 08:06:05�����5��5��' can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp
```

Can someone please explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

java.sql.timestamp cannot be initialized with value 0000-00-00 00:00:00. This is the reason for the error. Try importing with some other timestamp value in dateCreate column like  2011-02-15 02:02:02. It should work.